# clarification about argmin and critical point

Tags: calculus, slope

I just need a clarification regarding *argmin* and *minima* and *critical points*. As I understand it, $\text{argmin}_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}(4x^{2}-x^{4}):=\{-2,0,2\}$, but the minima of $(4x^{2}-x^{4}):=\{0\}$ and the corresponding critical point is $0$. Is this correct?

If yes, am I right in assuming that argmin does not always have to be the critical point (since there is no inflection)? Or, rather, non-critical points can also belong to the argmin set?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{argmin}$?

Comment: The argmin is *where* the min occurs (if any).  But your function $4x^2-x^4$ has no minimum, it has a max but no min.

Comment: A better example might be $y=x^2+2$.  The min is $y=2$ and the argmin is $x=0$.  And in this case there is no max or argmax.  Note the min if it exists is unique but the argmin need  not be.

Comment: Is it not $0$ at $x = 0$? When I differentiate it, I get $8x - 4x^3$, and $0$ is a critical point, no?

Comment: In your example, the argmin and critical points are same; I was wondering if it is okay for them to be different.

Comment: Critical points are not necessarily mins or maxes, a function may have no min or max.  Inflection points are neither.  Critical points are just *candidates* for where the max/min occurs but you have to do more work to check if they are or not.

Comment: How about $y=(x-1)^2+2$.  The min is $y=2$ and the argmin is $x=1$.  So no they don't have to be the same.

Comment: No at $x=0$ the function equals $2$ because.  $0^2+2=2$

Comment: In $y = (x-1)^2+2$, the critical point is 1. argmin is also $x = 1$. That is obvious. In $y = x^2 + 2$, it is of course clear that min is $2$.

I meant that in $y = 4x^2-x^4$, argmin is ${-2,0,2}$ and critical point (for minima) is ${0}$. The function has a minimum (refer your 1st comment).

Comment: If you replace $4x^2-x^4$ by its absolute value, your question begins to make sense. Another issue is that you are writing $\operatorname{argmin}_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}$, but when you consider the function only on the integers, the notion of critical point becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you. You are right; I should have set the function on real numbers before asking the question.

I did not understand how replacing by the absolute value makes a difference? To reiterate, the argmin of $(4x^2-x^4)$ is the set ${-2, 0, 2}$ and the min is $0$, right? Differentiating to obtain the critical points gives ${-\sqrt{2}, 0, \sqrt{2}}$. The critical point for minimum is ${0}$. This is a different set from the argmin set. My question was if this is okay? I suppose it is. But judging by the comments, I seem to have made some basic mistake/misunderstanding somewhere; I wonder where?